# Denied association (code=12) when connecting to 5GHz WLAN

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers, wlan, 802.1x

I'm using the **Archer T2U** as a WLAN adapter on my Debian machine and I cannot connect to my 5GHz home network. I can connect to my 2.4GHz network without any problems.

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7610U ("Archer T2U" 2.4G+5G WLAN Adapter
```

`dmesg`:

```
[   86.913331] wlan0: authenticate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[   86.965513] wlan0: send auth to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 1/3)
[   86.966267] wlan0: authenticated
[   86.968872] wlan0: associate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 1/3)
[   86.969758] wlan0: RX AssocResp from XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (capab=0x511 status=12 aid=11128)
[   86.969759] wlan0: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX denied association (code=12)
```

`uname -r`:

```
4.19.0-4-amd64
```

The 802.11 spec states that the code 12 stands for:

> Association denied due to reason outside the scope of this standard

and [Cisco's website](https://community.cisco.com/t5/wireless-mobility-documents/802-11-association-status-802-11-deauth-reason-codes/ta-p/3148055) lists this as an example:

> Example : When controller receives assoc from an unknown or disabled SSID

Is my router causing this issue? I assume it's not the driver since this is a fresh Debian installation and I doubt it's a hardware fault in the adapter since it is relatively new.

When using the adapter with a Windows machine it frequently disconnects from the 5GHz network but works flawlessly on the 2.4GHz network.

Comment: Nano usb model?

Comment: The full model number as specified by the manufacturer is **8853A-T2U**, IIRC it did not have *nano* in its name.

Comment: Nano is the size.

Comment: As I said, I do not remember it being called nano in any way. It believe it is [this one](https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/usb-adapter/archer-t2u/), although the box does look slightly different on the pictures.

Comment: It is not a nano indeed. Mind you I live in a well populated area and not so far am airport, the ap had to be moved next to my couch to take advantage of the 5GHz speeds. I would bet my money you are dealing with WiFi "features". I asked about nano, because they do not work well.

Comment: I live in a rural area not anywhere near an airport where there is only one other 5GHz network, so it's probably not interference. What do you mean with "WiFi features"?

Comment: That code 12 is a very ancient bug, if it is a bug. Wifi is not a simple protocol, and even less the 5GHz band. It does not cross walls and the distance to he AP has to be small. Then also hw implementations are notoriously bad, for instance, old ralink chipsets have nasty bugs. On top of it, it is preferable to have internal wifis to USB wifis and even I do not have the whole thecnical baggage to explain properly the *whys*. It is not a simple subject, but frequently the fault does not lies on the Linux/unix side of things.